# Aggregate over every permutation of two tables

Tags: mysql

There are three tables:

- `customers`
- `products`
- `sales`.

Every sales entry have a `customer_id` and `product_id`.

I need to `SELECT` and `SUM` the `sales.value` of each combination of `customers.id` and `products.id`. The point is: in the `sales` table, not every combination exists there, so I want that those combinations to have sum equal to zero in the results.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0f37a/2

This fiddle shows how the results should be, but I couldn't include lines for the combinations that doesn't exists and should sum 0. For example:

The combinations of customer_id 1 and product_id 1, 2 and 4 exists, not customer_id 1 and product_id 3. I want to include a line with this combination and sum(value) = 0.

EDIT

I have a table that contains every permutation of customer_id and product_id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try doing a `CROSS JOIN` between the `customers` and `products` tables to get all combinations, and then join that result to `sales`:

```
SELECT c.id AS customer_id, p.id AS product_id,
    COALESCE(CAST(s.value AS CHAR(6)), 'NA') AS value
FROM customers c
INNER JOIN products p
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON c.id = s.customer_id AND p.id = s.product_id
ORDER BY c.id, p.id
```

Note that a `CROSS JOIN` in MySQL is equivalent to doing an `INNER JOIN` with no `ON` criteria.

The link below is your Fiddle updated with the above query.

## SQLFiddle

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you.(Written in **MS SQLServer Syntax** but it should be close)

```
DECLARE @Cust TABLE (CID INT, CName VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Cust VALUES
(1, 'C1'  )     ,
(2, 'C2'  )     

DECLARE @Prod TABLE (PID INT, PName VARCHAR(5))

INSERT INTO @Prod VALUES
(1, 'P1'  )     ,
(2, 'P2'  )     ,
(3, 'P3'  )     ,
(4, 'P4'  )     


DECLARE @Sales TABLE (CID INT,  PID INT, Value INT )

INSERT INTO @Sales VALUES
(1, 1 , 10 )        ,
(1, 2 , 20 )        ,
(1, 4 , 30 )    


Select C.CID, P.PID, Sum(ISNULL(S.Value,0)) as Amt -- IFNULL in MySQL
from 
@Cust C Cross Join @Prod P
Left Outer JOIN @Sales S ON C.CID = S.CID AND P.PID = S.PID
Group By C.CID, P.PID
Order By 1
```